# What is the font used in the NYFW application?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, web-fonts

It looks like Roboto but the 'S' and width seems different.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font is Roboto Light. You can find this Google Font at https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto

[image: font ninja]